# How to call a function in useEffect only after getting data from backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect

What I have to achieve is to show the data obtained as response from api in sorted order from first render itself.

This is how I'm using useEffect hooks:-

```
useEffect(()=>{
        async function fetchProject() {
            await axios.post(envurls.wv+'/show_project',{
                params:{
                    authtoken:authtoken,
                    user:user
                }
            }).then((response)=>{
                console.log('Res', response.data);
                setShowProject(response.data)
                
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error)
            })
        }
        fetchProject();
        
    },[]);

    useEffect(() => {
        showProject.length> 0 && sortArray();
    }, []); 

   
    const sortArray = ()=> {
        const sortProperty = 'timestamp';
     
        sorted = [...showProject].sort((a, b) => (a[sortProperty] > b[sortProperty] ? -1 : 1))
        console.log("Project", showProject);
        console.log("Sorted Data", sorted);
        setShowProject(sorted);
    };
```

But on first render, it is not sorting data as showProject array is empty. So, I'm getting Project and Sorted Data as empty array on console.

And If I provide showProject in useEffect like this:-

```
useEffect(() => {
    showProject.length> 0 && sortArray();
}, [showProject]);
```

Then it is displaying sorted data for the first render itself but Project and Sorted Data are geetind displayed for n number of times in console.

Comment: Why does the sort array function need to be in a useEffect? Also, state filled by a fetch will _always be the default state_ on the first render.

Comment: Can't you sort it upon receiving it?

Comment: Because, I have to sortData depending on other states too like sorting type 'asc' or 'desc'. So each time user toggle from asc to desc. sortArray should get called. So I'll pass [sortType] as second parameter here to useEffect of sortArray

Comment: If the useEffect relies on the state `showProject` then it should be put into the dependency array. Also, you're not passing anything to `sortArray`

Comment: I tried to pass showProject but it is showing data n number of times in console. I forget to add it here.. I just edited the code.

Comment: This might get into an infinite render loop. As the useEffect runs when the `showProject` state has changed, but calls `sortArray` which changes the state.

Comment: Yes! That;s the issue

Comment: You can use `useMemo` and provide the required dependencies

Comment: Okk! Can you please elaborate. I'm not familier with useMemo

Comment: I have used async await there, then why it's not waiting for the data to be received before calling sortArray()??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) and set the dependencies to the data in state and the sorting parameters.

`useMemo` will call that function when one of the dependencies has changed exactly like `useEffect`, but this time it will return the value we return from that function.

This way we don't touch the original state and just sort it after changes

```js
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchProject() {
    const { data } = await axios.post(envurls.wv + "/show_project", {
      params: {
        authtoken: authtoken,
        user: user
      }
    });

    setShowProject(data);
  }

  fetchProject().catch(e => /* handle error here */);
}, []);

const sorted = useMemo(() => {
  const sortProperty = "timestamp";

  // use the sorting parameters here

  return [...showProject].sort((a, b) =>
    a[sortProperty] > b[sortProperty] ? -1 : 1
  );
}, [showProject, sortType]);

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: So You created a memo sorted but since its not a function what if want to pass sortProperty as an argument.

Comment: @AnkitJaishwal You save the `sortProperty` in state or pass it via `props` and include it in the dependencies array. This way when you update it `useMemo` will automatically re-run the function provided.

Comment: You can also just sort in render, but I think `useMemo` makes it cleaner and also will only run when needed

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the only way to get your "sorted data" on the first render is by passing the sorted data into the component through props. You are also needlessly updating your `showProject` twice which will cause unnecessary rerenders and @Asaf Aviv's answer is a good work around to that.

The best way to `call a function only after getting data from the backend` is to put the function call inside of the `.then()` callback or inside of and `async` function after an await. Right now your `sortArray()` is NOT doing either of those, it's outside the scope of your `async function` and `await` has no effect on it. The component renders, checks the `showProject.length> 0` condition, and if the condition is met it runs the function.

Also, you don't need to use `.then()` or `.catch()` inside of an async function, this is a more typical way to do it:

```
async function fetchProject() {
  try {
    let response = await axios.post(envurls.wv + "/show_project", {
      params: {
        authtoken: authtoken,
        user: user
      }
    });
    // everything past here runs ONLY AFTER getting a response back from axios.post
    setShowProject(response.data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```